# Javascript: Use var value as onclick window.open URL

Tags: javascript, onclick, window.open

How to use a var value and pass it to the `window.open` url? I'm really no good at this, so the simpler the better. Thank you very much!

```
<script>
    if (condition) {
        var URL = "http://www.url.com";
    } else {
        var URL = "http://www.url2.com"
    }
</script>
<div id="Banner" data-responsive="225h" onclick="window.open('URL','new_window');">
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice there's no quotes around the `URL` variable in `window.open`. Also to be more concise, I've moved the `var URL` portion out of the if/else logic.

```
<script>
    var URL;
    if (condition) {
        URL = "http://www.url.com";
    } else {
        URL = "http://www.url2.com"
    }
</script>
<div id="Banner" data-responsive="225h" onclick="window.open(URL,'new_window');">
```

An even better solution would be to get rid of your inline click handlers altogether like so:

```
<div id="Banner" data-responsive="225h"> ... </div>
<script>
    function openWindow() {
        var URL;
        if (condition) {
            URL = "http://www.url.com";
        } else {
            URL = "http://www.url2.com"
        } 
        window.open(URL,'new_window');
    }

    var banner = document.getElementById('Banner');
    banner.addEventListener('click', openWindow, false); //using addEventListener for brevity
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to mention moving `var` outside the `if`. That change may be overlooked.

Comment: Added an even better example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function a() {
   if (condition) {
     var URL = "http://www.url.com";
   }
   else {
    var URL = "http://www.url2.com"
   }
   window.open(URL);
  }
</script>
<div id="Banner" data-responsive="225h" onclick="a();">click me</div>
```

Alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

If the point of your question is to have a clickable, formatted html area, You can use an anchor  and have nested html elements inside it instead.I see this much cleaner.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
<p> I am an element inside an anchor</p>
<!-- you can put an image here instead -->
</a>

http://jsfiddle.net/CpXVB/
```